# PHP-PDO ODBC driver can't connect to MS Access MDB

Tags: php, pdo

I am having a really weird issue here.

Here is the context:

I have an old MS Access 97 .mdb file that I would like to use on a internal web page build in HTML, PHP, JQuery running on IIS.

Now I know that odbc drivers for php are already implemented but since I was already using PDO in some other pages linked to this I decided that I would also use PDO for this project.

So, after enabling the extension and all for PDO odbc drivers to work correctly, I copied the .mdb file and named it DBcopy.mdb into the project folder.

I wrote the code and perform some tests (to make sure everything worked as expected) and everything seems fine.

Than I change the path of the .mdb to //myothernetworkdrive/somedirectory/DBreal.mdb which is where the "real" .mdb file is and suddenly I get this message :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] SQLDriverConnect: -1032 [Microsoft][Pilote ODBC Microsoft Access] Le moteur de la base de données Microsoft Jet ne peut pas ouvrir le fichier '(Inconnu)'. Il est déjà ouvert en mode exclusif par un autre utilisateur, ou vous devez avoir l'autorisation de visualiser ses données.
```

For those of you who don't speak french here is a rought translation:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] SQLDriverConnect: -1032 [Microsoft][ODBC Drivers Microsoft Access] Microsoft Jet can't open file '(Inconnu)'. It is already open in exclusive mode by another user, or you need permission to access these data.
```

Since the error message is pretty self explained, I checked if someone was locking the .mdb file by looking for a .ldb file in the same directory but couldn't find one so I presume that the .mdb wasn't locked.

Anyone know why I can access the copy but not the original? The only difference I can see is are the directories there into:
Copy- is in the same folder as project.
Real- is on a network drive that IIS have the access

**EDIT:**

@Halayem Anis,
I don't use Apache, I am using IIS but since your point could be valid anyway I gave everyone permission to change/write/read/totalcontrol on the .mdb file but still the same error code.

**EDIT2:**

I am using this connection string:

```
new \PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=\\\\myothernetworkdrive\\somedirectory\\DBreal.mdb; UID=Admin; PWD=;");
```

Could it be that my connection string is not good?

**EDIT3:**

I added a DSN in my ODBC Driver manager in IIS with name 'testDSN' pointing to my .mdb file and I gave the IIS user total control on the .mdb file and the folder its in.

I also changed my connection string to:

```
new \PDO('odbc:testDSN');
```

But I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

The error message can drive you in the wrong way, please do these following steps :

1. To access to UNC Path via Apache you have to set a required credentials in Apache service (see service **=>** Apache **=>** LogOn)
2. Verify that the user used by Apache has access for read/write to your MDB file

Comment: Not using Apache but IIS still I gave everyone the permission to access the file. Still the same error message